# Wordpress создание своей таблицы

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Кто не будь знает по какой причине не работает конструкция

```
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->payment_info
```

при создание новой таблицы?
Такой вариант

```
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'payment_info'
```

не устраивает по той причине что потом нет возможности в запросе обратится через конструкцию

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->payment_info
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `dbDelta`. Пример:

```
global $wpdb;

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

$table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'test_table';
$charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$wpdb->charset} COLLATE {$wpdb->collate}";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name} (
    id  bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    address varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
    alert varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
    meta longtext NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    KEY alert (alert)
)
{$charset_collate};";

dbDelta($sql);
```

Если вы хотите добавить свою таблицу в свойства объекта:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_table' );
function register_my_table() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->payment_info = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'my_table_name';
}
```

Но лучше так не делать т.к. динамическое объявление свойсв объекта считается дурным тоном. Вместо этого если вы используете в своем коде классы создайте в нем свойсво, которое будете использовать, либо же константу.